# Stability property of Poisson equation with zero boundary values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose 
$$
-u''(x) = f(x)
$$
on $(0,1)$, and $u(0)=u(1)=0$, where $u$ is the unknown and $f$ is a continuous smooth term.

How to show that 
$$
\|u\|_ {\infty} \le  \frac{1}{8}\,\|f\|_{\infty} ?
$$

I was looking for Taylor's formula with integral remainder

Comment: on which set are you working?

Comment: For $x\in (0,1) $

Comment: I think you must also have boundary data

Comment: $u(0)=u(1)=0{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

you have

$$ -u''(x) = f(x)\implies -u'(t) = \int_0^tf(s)ds +c \implies -u(x) = \int_0^x \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds +c\right)dt+ a$$

$u(0)= 0$ then $a=0$ and $$u(1)= \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds +c\right)dt = \int_0^x \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds +c\right)dt =0  \\\implies  c=  -\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds \right)dt  $$
 This implies 
$$ -u(x) = -x\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds \right) +\int_0^x \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds \right)dt $$

$$|u(x)|\le \left(x\int_0^1 tdt +\int_0^x tdt\right)\|f\|_{\infty}$$

Comment: Thank you Guy Fsone, there are indeed these boundary conditions.

I will have a look to have sharper estimate ($1/8$) with your method.