# Solution of boundary value problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, integral-equations

> Consider a  boundary  value problem
>   $$
> \frac{\mathrm{d^2}y }{\mathrm{d} x^2 } =f(x)
> $$ 
>   with  boundary conditions 
>   $$
> y(0)=y(1)=\frac{dy}{dx}(1) 
> $$ 
>   where $f$ is  real-valued  continuous  function  on  the  interval $[0,1]$.
>
> Then  which  of  the following  is  true .
>
> - (1) Given  BVP  has  unique  solution for every  $f$.
> - (2) Given BVP  does not have unique solution  for  some  $f$.
> - (3) $y(x)=\int_{0}^{x}xtf(t)dt+\int_{x}^{1}(t-x+xt)f(t)dt$  is  the  solution  given BVP.
> - (4) $y(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(x-t+xt)f(t)dt+\int_{x}^{1}xtf(t)dt$  is the  solution  of  given  BVP.

for  this  i use

> **Theorem: Existence and  Uniqueness**   Let $p(t)$,  $q(t)$,  and $g(t)$ be continuous on  $[a,b]$ , then  the  differential  equation   $$y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y = g(t)\\ y(t_0) = y_0 \\   y'(t_0) = y'_0$$   has  a  unique solution defined  for all  $t$ in  $[a,b]$.

Therefore  we  have  unique  solution for  every  $f$ . Reject  option (2 ). Option (1) is  correct .

for option (4) I  directly  put  $x=0$ and  $1$  in  given solution  in the option. But I  get $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)= \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$. Clearly  both are  not  always equal.  so I  reject  option  (4).

For option (3)  I  differentiate given solution  in option  (3) i.e  $$y(x)=\int_{0}^{x}xtf(t)dt+\int_{x}^{1}(t-x+xt)f(t)dt$$  and i  get given  BVP. So according to  me  answers  should  be (1) and  (3).

please solve this problem. This is very important to me . you can just tell me the correct options .

Comment: Please tell us what you tried and where you are stuck at? So we can help you better,

Comment: i add my approach to the question . you can check it now .please help me now .

Comment: it is very important to me please reply anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The uniqueness is obvious Now we jump to the existence:

Doing like here [Stability property of Poisson equation with zero boundary values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562378/stability-property-of-poisson-equation-with-zero-boundary-values) you have
$$ y''(x) = f(x)\implies y'(t) = \int_0^tf(s)ds +c \\\implies y(x) = \int_0^x \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds +c\right)dt+ a$$

Now $$y(0) = a = y(1) =  \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds +c\right)dt+ a $$

Then $$\int_0^ 1\left(\int_0^tf(s)ds +c\right)dt=0\implies c=-\int_0^ 1\int_0^tf(s)ds dt  $$

also $$y(0) =a= y'(1) = \int_0^1f(s)ds +c=  \int_0^1f(s)ds-\int_0^ 1\int_0^tf(s)ds dt  $$

Therefore,  $$y(x) = \int_0^x \left(\int_0^tf(s)ds +c\right)dt+ a\\=\int_0^x \int_0^tf(s)dsdt -x\int_0^ 1\int_0^tf(s)ds dt + \int_0^1f(s)ds-\int_0^ 1\int_0^tf(s)ds dt $$

Comment: Values of a and c can be find this means  option 1 and 3 are correct  .am I right sir ?

Comment: @guronkar yes 3 and 1 are correct. Don't forget to vote and checkmark if the solution suite you